# Magento showing error

Tags: magento

There has been an error processing your request

SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 Can't create/write to file '/tmp/#sql_1b47_0.MYI' (Errcode: 28)

Trace:

```
#0 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT `cms_pag...', Array)
#4 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT `cms_pag...', Array)
#5 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(753): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(380): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchRow(Object(Varien_Db_Select))
#7 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Resource/Page.php(170): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Cms_Model_Page), 'home', 'identifier')
#8 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Abstract.php(225): Mage_Cms_Model_Resource_Page->load(Object(Mage_Cms_Model_Page), 'home', NULL)
#9 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Model/Page.php(113): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load('home', NULL)
#10 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(74): Mage_Cms_Model_Page->load('home')
#11 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#12 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(45): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'home')
#13 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Cms_IndexController->indexAction()
#14 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#15 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#16 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#17 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#18 /home3/xtremesu/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#19 {main}
```

Comment: How much space do you have on the database server?

Comment: it is 1 GB, it is sufficient space for a magento normal site.

Comment: If you say so. My bet is that mysql can't create temp files cause it doesn't have enough free space.

Comment: 1GB?, umm, no... Innodb grows due to temporary table use and easily exceeds your arbitrary low figure. Another Magento site down due to failure to properly allocate resources.